Ubuntu 24.04 freezing with AI 9 HX 370
I have an Asus Zenbook S16 with a new AMD Ryzen AI 9 HX 370 processor.
Most things seem to work pretty well, but apart from bluetooth not working, the only problem, that I really have is, that the laptop randomly freezes off completely. (mouse not movable, nothing working anymore until I force shut it down)
I already installed latest apt-get dist-upgrades and and tried to check journalctl and syslogs, but I cannot find anything related to this.
The computer does not seem to run hot and it happens, even without anything running or workload. The timing is also random. Sometimes it's after 4 minutes, sometimes it works for 1 hour and then freezes.
Not sure how to debug this further. Appreciate any help or tips what/how to check this further, because atm this is unusable.
Here is the output of inxi:
➜  ~ inxi -F
System:
  Host: simons-asus Kernel: 6.11.0-12-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 47.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular Oriole)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ASUS Zenbook S 16 UM5606WA_UM5606WA
    v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UM5606WA v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: UM5606WA.312 date: 11/01/2024
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 57.5 Wh (72.7%) condition: 79.1/78.0 Wh (101.4%)
    volts: 8.2 min: 8.0
CPU:
  Info: 12-core model: AMD Ryzen AI 9 HX 370 w/ Radeon 890M bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1596 min/max: 599/4367 cores: 1: 2000 2: 2000 3: 2000
    4: 2000 5: 1394 6: 1394 7: 1394 8: 1394 9: 1394 10: 1394 11: 1394 12: 1394
    13: 2000 14: 2000 15: 2000 16: 2000 17: 1394 18: 1394 19: 1394 20: 1409
    21: 1394 22: 1394 23: 1394 24: 1394
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Strix [Radeon 880M / 890M] driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: Shinetech ASUS FHD webcam driver: hid-sensor-hub,usbhid,uvcvideo
    type: USB
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 24.1.2 with: Xwayland v: 24.1.2
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1200~120Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,radeonsi,swrast
    platforms: gbm,wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.2.3-1ubuntu1
    renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics (radeonsi gfx1150 LLVM 19.1.0 DRM 3.58
    6.11.0-12-generic)
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_acp_pci
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.11.0-12-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.2.4 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: MEDIATEK driver: mt7925e
  IF: wlp195s0 state: up mac: c0:bf:be:2b:5e:16
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks Wireless_Device driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
    address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 87.59 GiB (9.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: MTFDKBA1T0QFM-1BD1AABGB
    size: 953.87 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 757.36 GiB used: 87.49 GiB (11.6%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 104.2 MiB (40.7%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 38.2 C mobo: 31.0 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 36.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Info:
  Memory: total: 32 GiB note: est. available: 29.96 GiB used: 3.27 GiB (10.9%)
  Processes: 524 Uptime: 1m Shell: Zsh inxi: 3.3.35

Update:
I now even updated to the latest kernel from mainline:
System:
  Host: simon-asus Kernel: 6.12.3-061203-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 47.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular Oriole)

but it still crashes.

Run: inxi -F, edit your post and paste the output of that command.

@kyodake thanks for answering. did just that.

Has similar problem with Asus Vivobook M5406WA Ryzen AI 9 HX 370. Tried different BIOS (now is v.308) - all have random freezes.
But after I downgraded kernel to 6.11 - freezes almost disappear (may be one in 1-2 day)
Now I'm waiting 6.13, that has many improvements to AMD drivers
